# How to access properties of a control that is nested within ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I want to know that how we can access properties of a control that is nested within ListView template??

I have a CheckBox control within ListView template but does not appear in the IntelliSense when I try to access it in code behind file.

Please tell me how can access the properties of that CheckBox in codeBehind file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ItemDataBound` event to get a reference to the `CheckBox` control. In the `ItemDataBound` event handler, you can use the `FindControl` method (from the passed in `ListViewItemEventArgs`) to get a reference to any control declared in the `ItemTemplate`.

To wire up `ItemDataBound` from the front page, simply do something like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv1" OnItemDataBound="lv1_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
```

To get a reference to a `CheckBox` (see full example below), the code looks like this:

```
private void lv1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    //Get a reference and check each checkbox
    var chk = e.Item.FindControl("chkOne") as CheckBox;
    if (chk != null)
        chk.Checked = true;
}
```

Here is a full example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ListView ID="lv1" OnItemDataBound="lv1_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate><div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></div></LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div><asp:CheckBox ID="chkOne" Runat="server" /> <%# Container.DataItem %></div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script runat="server">
public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var items = new List<string> { "Item #1", "Item #2", "Item #3" };
        lv1.DataSource = items;
        lv1.DataBind();
    }
}

private void lv1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    //Get a reference and check each checkbox
    var chk = e.Item.FindControl("chkOne") as CheckBox;
    if (chk != null)
        chk.Checked = true;
}
</script>
```